# How to disable/not choose SWYPE keyboard for an EditText if an alternate soft keyboard is available?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have a Samsung Galaxy Y with android 2.3.6. My app has a simple activity with an EditText. I want that when the EditText gets focus, whose layout says android:inputType="number", the non SWYPE (samsung) soft keyboard shows up.How can I tell my app/EditText to do that by default?

The reason I want to do that is the SWYPE has a lot more button keys(Settings and another custom Tutorial/Help) that I dont want in the soft keyboard for this Edit Text. I just need numbers + Done for that matter.

An help would be appreciated! Thnx.